# Compare entire rows for equality if some condition is satisfied

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following data of a match in a CSV file:

```
name,match1,match2,match3
Alice,2,4,3
Bob,2,3,4
Charlie,1,0,4
```

I'm writing a python program. Somewhere in my program I have scores collected for a match stored in a list, say `x = [1,0,4]`. I have found where in the data these scores exist using pandas and I can print "found" or "not found". However I want my code to print out to which `name` these scores correspond to. In this case the program should output "charlie" since charlie has all these values `[1,0,4]`. how can I do that?

I will have a large set of data so I must be able to tell which name corresponds to the numbers I pass to the program.

Comment: To be clear, you don't want to just compare one column, you want to compare the three columns `match1,match2,match3` against a given list `[1,0,4]`

Comment: yes all columns, and print out the correct name accordingly

Comment: I would retitle it *"Compare entire rows for equality"*. *"if some condition is satisfied"* is very vague.

Comment: Welcome to SO. [You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on the big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can also upvote answers by clicking on the upper gray triangle.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354584/teaching-new-users-how-to-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here's how to compare entire rows in a dataframe:

```
df[(df == x).all(axis=1)].index   # where x is the pd.Series we're comparing to
```

Also, it makes life easiest if you directly set `name` as the index column when you read in the CSV.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = """\
name,match1,match2,match3
Alice,2,4,3
Bob,2,3,4
Charlie,1,0,4"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df), index_col='name')

x = pd.Series({'match1':1, 'match2':0, 'match3':4})
```

Now you can see that doing `df == x`, or equivalently `df.eq(x)`, is not quite what you want because it does element-wise compare and returns a row of True/False. So you need to aggregate those rows with `.all(axis=1)` which finds rows where all comparison results were `True`...

```
df.eq(x).all(axis=1)

df[ (df == x).all(axis=1) ]
#         match1  match2  match3
# name
# Charlie       1       0       4
```

...and then finally since you only want the `name` of such rows:

```
df[ (df == x).all(axis=1) ].index
# Index(['Charlie'], dtype='object', name='name')

df[ (df == x).all(axis=1) ].index.tolist()
# ['Charlie']
```

which is what you wanted. (I only added the spaces inside the expression for clarity).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DataFrame.loc which would work like this:

```
print(df.loc[(df.match1 == 1) & (df.match2 == 0) & (df.match3 == 4), 'name'])
```

Comment: this returns 
0      Alice
1        Bob
2    Charlie

is there a way to only return Charlie?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Makes sample data
match1 = np.array([2,2,1])
match2 = np.array([4,4,0])
match3 = np.array([3,3,4])
name = np.array(['Alice','Bob','Charlie'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': id, 'match1': match1, 'match2':match2, 'match3' :match3})
df

# example of the list you want to get the data from
x=[1,0,4]
#x=[2,4,3]

# should return the name Charlie as well as the index (based on the values in the list x) 
df['name'].loc[(df['match1'] == x[0]) & (df['match2'] == x[1]) & (df['match3'] ==x[2])]

# Makes a new dataframe out of the above 
mydf = pd.DataFrame(df['name'].loc[(df['match1'] == x[0]) & (df['match2'] == x[1]) & (df['match3'] ==x[2])])

# Loop that prints out the name based on the index of mydf
# Assuming there are more than one name, it will print all. if there is only one name, it will print only that)
for i in range(0,len(mydf)):
      print(mydf['name'].iloc[i])
```

Comment: this returns 
0      Alice
1        Bob
2    Charlie
when I apply it to a cvs file, is there a way to only return Charlie without the other names and indices?

Comment: Yep. Just edited my answer. The solution might depend on exactly how your data is organised though. Assuming match1-3 are separate columns and each item in the list x are the values you want to match for matc1,match2 and amtch3, this should work.

Comment: the main issue here is that I don't know what the index will be beforehand, my program should be able to look for the name corresponding to the values without me giving it an index. print(mydf['name'].iloc[0]) this line here only prints what index I give it as far as I understand

Comment: You dont need to know the index beforehand. The new dataframe mydf will contain whatever name or names match the values you specify in the list x and then it just gives you the first name. It will also show you if there is more than one match (in which case just change the .iloc[0] to .iloc[:]

Comment: Isn't this too complicated and also not an efficient way. You should try and use pd.Series to get this done quicker.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

here **data** is your Data frame ,you can change accordingly your data frame name,

and

> considering [1,0,4] is int type

```
data = data[(data['match1']== 1)&(data['match2']==0)&(data['match3']== 4 ).index

print(data[0])
```

> if data is object type then use this

```
data = data[(data['match1']== "1")&(data['match2']=="0")&(data['match3']== "4" ).index

print(data[0])
```